# How do I remove all frames from current windows in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before posting to another page from my center frame, I want to remove the top and bottom frames so that I don't see my spinner or footer show up in the page I'm posting to.

Can I use something like this?:

```
jQuery("#frmHeader").remove();
jQuery("#frmFooter").remove();
```

I don't want to remove the body frame b/c I am posting from that frame to Login Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any other frame you can set `target` property of your `form` to `_top`.

```
<form method="post" action="/login/" target="_top">
```

If you're redirecting user with a link you can use `target` attribute too.

```
<a href="/login/" target="_top">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.remove()` to pull those frames out, but it will likely disrupt the layout of your page. Is the entire page updating after your post completes or only your body frame?

Comment: I only want to do it during a form submit operation. So the user shouldn't notice.